# Android webview blank when come back on the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

I'hv used webview to show data called by web service.
If data show in webview i am go to next fragment and then come back to previous fragment the webview is blank. Is any way to preserve the data once it load in application?

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html,"text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

The "html" string contains the HTML code.

Comment: post your relative code

Comment: webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html,"text/html", "utf-8", null); the html string contains the HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

1) Create this interface in your activity

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
        private Context context;

        public JavaScriptInterface(Context activiy) {
            this.context = activiy;
        }

        public void onVideoClick(String sourceAddress) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(sourceAddress), "video/3gpp");
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

2) In your code write these lines before loadData in webview.

```
JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface(this);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");

String newHtml = html.replaceAll("<video width=\"[0-9]*", "<video width=\"100\\%\" onclick=\"window.JSInterface.onVideoClick(src);\"");

webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, newHtml,"text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: I have save the html sting in constant sting variable. when i come back on previous fragment assign that string to the webview. and it's work for me. thanks for replay.